# c# Gitlab get api pagination

Tags: c#, async-await, get, gitlab-api

I wrote a method which calls to Gitlab API but I cannot get more than 47 projects. 
When I call this method like this:

```
List<Projects> projects = GetProject("/api/v4/projects?per_page=47").Result; 
List<Projects> projects = GetProject("/api/v4/projects?per_page=20&page=1").Result; 
List<Projects> projects = GetProject("/api/v4/projects?per_page=20&page=2").Result;
```

it work fines, but this:

```
List<Projects> projects = GetProject("/api/v4/projects?per_page=48").Result; 
List<Projects> projects = GetProject("/api/v4/projects?per_page=20&page=3").Result; 
List<Projects> projects = GetProject("/api/v4/projects?per_page=10&page=5").Result;
```

It doesn't work and I get `System.AggregateException` on `RunAsync().Wait();`.. Every time when I try to get more than 47. I checked in RESTer and when I call GET like this:

```
https://local/api/v4/projects?per_page=48
```

It works and I get an answer that there are 1474 projects,31 pages:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Can you display the exception detail, mostly the inner exception.

Comment: ` This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]  
Inner Exception 1:AggregateException: One or more errors occurred
Inner Exception 2:JsonSerializationException: Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Boolean'. Path '[9].packages_enabled', line 1, position 30094.
Inner Exception 3:InvalidCastException: Null object cannot be converted to a value type`

Comment: See this `JsonSerializationException: Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Boolean'. Path '[9].packages_enabled'`. In the DTO `Projects`, the property `packages_enable`need be of type `bool?`.

Comment: Yuuup that was it. Now, I found another similar errors in DTO Projects. It's all because I used "Paste special > Paste JSON as Classes"  

Tnx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my pagination problem in this post: stackoverflow.com/a/64855501/10522472